# drupal 7 link to theme image

Tags: drupal-7

This seems like a very basic question, but I have been googling around and can't get a good answer.

given 
sites/all/themes/phppos/img/demo.png

What is the CORRECT way to create an image take front page--front.tpl.php?

I have tried the below: (I get modules/system/img/demo.png)

```
<?php echo theme('image', array('path' => path_to_theme() .'/img/demo.png')); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `modules/system/img/demo.png` as the resulting path because you're calling the `path_to_theme()` function within the `theme()` function.

According to the [documentation for `path_to_theme()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) :

> ...when invoked within the scope of a theming call it will depend on
>   where the theming function is handled.

Try using [`drupal_get_path('theme', $theme_name)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_path/7) instead.

Comment: This seems so ridiculous just for an image:


<?php echo theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'phppos') .'/img/demo.png')); ?>

Comment: @ChrisMuench Did it work?  I'm just going by your original code.

Comment: Yeah it works, it would be nice if there was some sort of image helper function though.

Comment: That is Drupal's helper function for images :-) The point of the theme system is to give other modules/themes the chance to override the output for commonly outputted elements. For example Drupal core uses it to add RDFa attributes to images where appropriate. It's not easy giving yourself over to Drupal (a lot of it feels very...dirty at times), but it does also have it's upsides